# How to download and run an existing Zend Site?

Tags: php, zend-framework, xampp

I have not every used, or even installed the Zend Framework.
I have inherited a website built in the ZF and only have FTP access to the deployed version that is live.

Is it possible to simply download the files that are live and run then locally within XAMPP, as i have tried this but ther server has lots of short cut director mappings and no ZEND?

I am assuming not, so can i install Zend and then download the site to my local machine for it then to work?

Any assistance on this would be helpful as have no idea about it, whether i need source files or not.

Thanks

Shaun

Answer (score 1):

once you have the project downloaded in xampp. make sure you have composer installed and configured.

delete the vendor folder inside your project then run

```
composer install
```

under the root of your application.